# Какая разница между тавтологией и плеоназмом?

Tags: тавтология, плеоназм

Я так понял, что разница в том, что плеоназм это речевая избыточность, то есть когда какое-то слово обозначает то, что уже входит в определение другого слова, как сочетания: ‟коллеги по работе”, ‟единогласный консенсус”, ‟героический подвиг”; а тавтология это вообще не речевая избыточность, а просто разновидность грамотейского невроза, когда грамотеям по какой-то причине не нравятся сочетания родственных слов, как: ‟сегодняшний день”, ‟варить варенье”(варенье можно есть, выбрасывать, продавать, готовить), ‟в рассказе рассказывается”(в таких сочетаниях нужна подобного рода связка).

Просто ничего не понятно. Взгляните на первую картинку по этой теме, которая выпадает в поисковике:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ПЛЕОНАЗМ**
Своя автобиография. (Автобиография это книга, и я могу держать в руке как свою автобиографию, так и чужую автобиографию. Если я всё правильно понимаю, то это вообще не речевая избыточность и не тавтология.)
Ностальгия по родине. (Ностальгировать можно по чему угодно. Это сочетание не плеоназм и не тавтология.)
Коллеги по работе. (Это действительно плеоназм, если я всё правильно понимаю.)

**ТАВТОЛОГИЯ**
В рассказе рассказывается. (Тавтология.)
Подарили в дар. (Если я всё правильно понимаю, то это и плеоназм, и тавтология.)
Проливной ливень. (Если я всё правильно понимаю, то это и плеоназм, и тавтология.)

Я, конечно, понимаю, что это лингвистика и здесь качественные формализации, определения, классификации — редкость, но статьи по этой теме даже для этой ‟науки” просто дикость.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Розенталь:
Объектом лексической правки должны быть также употребленные без стилистического задания плеоназмы (обороты речи, содержащие однозначные и, тем самым, обычно лишние слова) и тавтологии (повторение сказанного близкими по смыслу словами, часто однокоренными), а также многословие.

Требуют правки предложения, содержащие однокоренные тавтологические выражения или слова, образованные от одного и того же корня (исключается, естественно, стилистически заданное употребление). Например: «В борьбе против коррупции рабочие объединились воедино»; «Наряду с достижениями был отмечен ряд недостатков»; «Подбирая иллюстрации к книге, необходимо при их подборе учитывать художественные их достоинства»; «В заключение рассказчик рассказал еще одну забавную историю»; «Добиваясь высокой производительности труда, новаторы производства одновременно добиваются значительной экономии издержек производства»; «Не без труда удалось решить эти сложные и трудные проблемы»; «Следует иметь в виду, что частицы пыли, имеющие острые грани, при ударах о волокна разрушают ткань»; «Продолжительность процесса длится несколько часов»; «К недостаткам диссертации нужно отнести недостаточную разработку отдельных частных вопросов»; «Как и следовало ожидать, все разъяснилось на следующий же день»; «Следует отметить следующие особенности рассматриваемого проекта...»; «В ответ на это мы получили такой ответ...»

Явно лишние слова содержатся в приводимых ниже предложениях: «Было установлено, что существующие расценки завышены» («несуществующие» расценки не могут быть ни завышены, ни занижены); «Незаконное растаскивание государственного имущества...» (растаскивание государственного имущества не может быть «законным»); «Перед своей смертью он написал завещание» (завещание не пишут перед чужой смертью); «Успешно проводится обмен имеющимся опытом» (если опыта не имеется, то нельзя им и обмениваться); «В своем докладе на тему о магнитных усилителях молодой ученый сообщил о найденных им новых формах их применения» (в чужом докладе не сообщают о своих открытиях или наблюдениях).
http://rus-yaz.niv.ru/doc/rules-rosental/articles/141-pleonazmy-i-tavtologii.htm

Во втором абзаце про тавтологию, а в третьем — про плеоназм.

> Если я всё правильно понимаю, то это

Вы правильно понимаете.